# tensorflow-serving signature for an XOR

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to export my first xor NN using tensorflow serving but I am not getting any result when I call the gRPC.
Here the code I use to predict the XOR

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(sess)
K.set_learning_phase(0)  # all new operations will be in test mode from now on

from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as saved_model_builder
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants, signature_constants, signature_def_utils_impl

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np

model_version = "2" #Change this to export different model versions, i.e. 2, ..., 7
epoch = 100 ## the higher this number is the more accurate the prediction will be 10000 is a good number to s
et it at just takes a while to train

#Exhaustion of Different Possibilities
X = np.array([
    [0,0],
    [0,1],
    [1,0],
    [1,1]
])

#Return values of the different inputs
Y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

#Create Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=2))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=1, nb_epoch=epoch)

test = np.array([[0.0,0.0]])

#setting values for the sake of saving the model in the proper format
x = model.input
y = model.output

print('Results of Model', model.predict_proba(X))

prediction_signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def({"inputs": x}, {"prediction":
y})

valid_prediction_signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.is_valid_signature(prediction_signature)
if(valid_prediction_signature == False):
    raise ValueError("Error: Prediction signature not valid!")

builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder('./'+model_version)
legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')

# Add the meta_graph and the variables to the builder
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
      sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
      signature_def_map={
           signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:prediction_signature,
      },
      legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)

# save the graph
builder.save()
```

Implement in docker

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/root/tensorflow3/projects/example/xor_keras_tensorflow_serving,target=/models/xor -e MODEL_NAME=xor -t tensorflow/serving &
```

then I request the prediction by the following:

```
curl -d '{"inputs": [1,1]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v2/models/xor
```

the result is always this

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Not Found</H1>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Can you help me to find where I wrong?
I have tried to change "inputs" in the curl with "instances", but nothing
Thanks,
Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you first try

> curl http://localhost:8501/v1/models/xor

to check if the model is running? This should return the status of your model.

From [RESTful API doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/97687024c3b7515d2f2979c35054f44c8f84d146/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/api_rest.md#model-status-api), the format is `GET http://host:port/v1/models/${MODEL_NAME}[/versions/${MODEL_VERSION}]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! you got the point! so I solved.

Actually there were 2 errors to the curl command:

1. localhost:8501/**v1**/models/xor  I put v2 thinking to use the version #2, but if you put v2 it does not work. It seems v# it is not the versiono of your saved model
2. Also I need to specify the predict so the exact request is: **http://localhost:8501/v1/models/xor:predict**

Comment: glad to help. just edited my answer about model version.

Comment: Thanks Yiding, very appreciated!